# Jewellery and custom Cloth modeling

Tags: modeling

I am a writer and working on my short stories so I chose blender to make 3d short film..And I think I am an intermediate but now I am confused that how to make jewellery and custom cloth for indian character.. Please guide me, I need help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please show what you have tried that did not work and detail what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of great tutorials on YouTube on modeling and simulating clothes in blender. Here are a couple of links:

https://youtu.be/szEeu6_b4fg
https://youtu.be/u6CN08r7WVA

As for the jewelry, blender has an add on (I believe it comes with blender) called “Extra Objects.” In it it has an option for diamonds and gems. It’s a good start for creating a variety of classic looking gems; with some extra modeling you’ll achieve the look you’re going for.

For both the cloth and gems (depending on your style) a good understanding of adding materials (UV unwrapping, nodes, texturing, etc.) will really help you get the look you’re going for.

It’ll take time and patience to learn this stuff but having a well rounded understanding of these things will help you in this and many other projects you do.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have tested some curvy jewelry the other day. So you can use this file for free if you want, or maybe get some inspiration.

Download file here: [image]

[image]